# Почему HelloService возвращает ссылку на наш класс Hello?

Tags: java, java-ee

Вот статья http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html#bnayr

Вопрос - откуда в коде клиента взялся некий HelloService, который возвращает ссылку на наш класс Hello?

Comment: По всей видимости из примеров, на которые постоянно ссылаются в статье (tut-install/javaeetutorial5/examples).

Comment: @Олег Михайлов, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.